# How to make crawlers ignore my disclaimer

Tags: asp.net, web-crawler

I have a disclaimer on my site that is shown once in a session.
Once clicked, you are allowed in a certain section, and it will be remembered in your session so it won't bug you again.

Problem is, I dont want crawlers to encounter the disclaimer at all. What is did was to ignore Googlebot User-agent.

But There are many other crawlers which I want them to ignore that too.

Is that the only solution? to identify a crawler by its UA? what about detecting the cookie - if I dont have a cookie, it means its a crawler?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want the crawlers to see the content "protected by" the disclaimer page or not?

Comment: yes. that is why I want them to have the "privilege" to skip it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want to rely on a cookie for this anyway, as a user could disable cookies on a regular browser.

Use the UA for your purposes, and just get the big crawlers, updating now and again.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file in the root of your site called robots.txt.

In it, put this:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
Disallow: /path/to/disclaimer
```

You can find more info about robots.txt [on the web](https://www.google.com/search?q=robots.txt).

Comment: But they won't be able to get to the next page (since the disclaimer redirects them)

Comment: @Himberjack: That raises a design problem: If you don't want users to access the "content" page without first going through the disclaimer, then if the content page is indexed on a search engine, the user could find it on the search engine and click through directly to it without seeing the disclaimer. The only solution to this that I can think of is to make the disclaimer and the content have the same URL. i.e. when the user first sees the page, he gets the disclaimer, then he clicks okay and the page that comes back as the same URL but different text, presumably controlled by a back end.

Comment: No. If the page will be on google, and the user will click on it, he will go to the disclaimer, because every request I check if he had accepted it in the session

Comment: You check it on the server? How does the user accept the disclaimer? By clicking a link? Or by checking a box and submitting a POST?

Comment: POST and the server puts it in his session

Comment: OK I understand now. You want crawlers to index the content in the disclaimed section of your site. But, when the crawlers access it, you don't want them to index the disclaimer. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can have the crawlers see the disclaimer page but not index it by adding a "noindex" meta tag to the page.  This could be a partial solution to your problem.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
        <title>Disclaimer</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

This way, crawlers will be able to access the pages behind the disclaimer, but they won't actually index based on terms on the disclaimer page.